# PHP mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given

Tags: php

I've tried various suggestions for this but am getting nowhere. I am moving a PHP site (authored by someone else) to a new domain. After the move, I get these errors across my site:
 mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given..

The lines referred to by an example error are:

```
 <div id="desc"><p align="center"><?php mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);
```

$con does not appear anywhere else.

each page includes dbc.php, which has the code

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: "$con does not appear anywhere else." That should be a tell

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `mysql_select_db_()` should be the value returned by `mysql_connect()`. So you should use `$link`, not `$con`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
mysql_connect('hostname','username','password');
mysql_select_db('databasename');
```

you won't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
 <div id="desc"><p align="center"><?php
     $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS)
          $db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link)
```

You can select MySQL database without using this function.
Simply right after connecting to MySQL

```
<?php $connection = mysql_connect("datatbasehost", "username", "password"); ?>
```

perform this query:

```
<?php mysql_query("USE somedatabase", $connection); ?>
```